# I am mysteriously getting 11200 error from Twilio (403 Forbidden on callback)

Tags: twilio

I am trying to keep a log of the status of our Twilio messages sent from our Rails app (we send a reminder message to users every day). Occasionally, I get this error (seen on the Twilio console as "Error 11200") for some of the callback attempts:

Msg "Request to StatusCallback URL was not successful."

httpResponse    "403"

The messages from Twilio *are* actually getting sent, but it appears that sometimes the callback mysteriously fails with a code that indicates an auth problem with Twilio accessing our servers. Specifically, in the Response Header, I see this:
Status 403 Forbidden

Can anyone help me figure out why this is happening? 90% of the time the callbacks work perfectly (i.e. I can see in our logs that the Twilio sms status goes through "accepted", "queued", "sent", "delivered". But some of the time the callback is mysteriously rejected with a 403. Thanks for any insight into this!

Here is the single line of authentication code (using the twilio-ruby gem):
`use Rack::TwilioWebhookAuthentication, TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN, '/checkstatus'`

Comment: Can you share the action that the status callback webhook is hitting and any middleware that you are including before the action?

Comment: Sure - really, it's not even getting to our actual callback since it seems that the auth is randomly failing. Here is the 1-line auth code in our twilio_controller.rb file:  

`use Rack::TwilioWebhookAuthentication, TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN, '/checkstatus'`

Comment: Huh, I wrote that middleware and it should work fine. It especially shouldn't work only 90% of the time. How are you providing the auth token to the middleware? Where are you calling that line beginning with `use`? Shouldn't it be in your `config/environments/production.rb`?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? I'm having a similar problem.